# iPhone:Query about audio Player

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Which Audio Player is this??

[image]

I want to add the Above player in my iPhone App

How Can I include it to my App ?

and  I want to play Audio files from server (without downloading)  so how can I achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/simple-way-to-play-mp3-audio-files
- http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html
- http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

He's got a project linked from that page - http://projectswithlove.com/projects/iPhoneStreamingPlayer.zip

Answer (score 0):

this is a custom made player. check out this project https://github.com/jfricker/AudioStreamer/

you just need to design similar interface.